# Cannot install build on my device (Reconnect device always required)

Tags: testflight

My device is registered in the distribution provisioning profile, the profile is uploaded to Test Flight, a build is prepared and sent to my device. I got the email, clicked in the `Install` button, and I start getting a screen with button that says `Reconnect Device`, I connected my device through Safari, logged in to test flight and TF said that my device now is `successfully connected`so I build another `ipa` and sent it to my device, but gotting always the same issue, `Reconnect Device` button. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble recently. Tried reconnected my devices (2) a few times, only to find out that their UDIDs got changed in TestFlight on uploading a new build, so the build was still not available for my devices. I tried removing wrong UDID's in TestFlight, keeping the right ones, but it didn't solve the problem.

What finally helped was this:

1. removing all apps installed from TestFlight on all of my devices
2. removing **all** UDID's from my TestFlight account
3. reconnecting my devices to TestFlight

Let me know if it helps in your case. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We have received a lot of "reconnect device" messages on iPhones lately and, at least for one tester, we have found a workaround. Instead of following the email links, the user had do install the build from within the TestFlight mobile app.